# How to do rails tests on a large dataset (10gb)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing

I have a project with a large set of climate data. I want do some of the tests on the whole dataset (10GB). Is there a way to import a dump once when launching the tests so that I can use the dataset in all tests (I do only read the data).

If I put the import command in a setup method I'll have to import the 10gigs several times, which is too slow.

Comment: What do you really want to test? Functional aspects? Performance? If you only want to test functional aspects I'd say you won't want to run the tests over the whole 10GB of data.